# Yii2, merge two active query condictions in a join

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii, yii2

In one of my project i've got two entity rappresented as tables in my database.

1. Entity A (called from now on A)
2. Entity B (called from now on B)

Entity A have 1:n relation with B.

With yii2 i've created both ActiveRecord Models with relations (gii automatic creation).

In a certain controller of my project i generate (by a model function) two active queryies:

```
$query1 = \app\models\A::generateQuery(); // Return \app\models\A::find()->where([//condictions for A])

$query2 = \app\models\B::generateQuery(); // Return \app\models\B::find()->where([//condictions for B])
```

Before find the results i want join the two Entity and concatenate the where condictions of both but maintain them as indipendent active queryies.

A ideal rappresentation of command should be:

```
$query1->join($query2);
```

And the sql result should be this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A JOIN B ON a.id = b.rif_a_entity 
WHERE a.field = 1 AND b.field = 2
```

I tried with [joinWith](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#joinWith%28%29-detail) approach, but it doesn't seem work in my case.
Anyone had a similar problem?

Thanks for all the help

Comment: posted an answer for you see if that helps you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `leftJoin` to achieve this in the following way

```
app\models\A::find()
->leftJoin('{{%B}}', '{{%A}}.[[id]] = {{%B}}.[[rif_a_entity]]')
->where(['=','{{%A}}.[[field]]',1])
->andWhere(['=','{{%B}}.[[field]]',1])
->all();
```

to verify if the above query is generating the right sql you need remove the 
`->all()` from the last line an replace with `->createCommand()->rawSql` and echo the whole query like below and adjust accordingly. you can copy that `SQL` and run in you `phpmyadmin` window to verify the result sets too

```
app\models\A::find()
->leftJoin('{{%B}}', '{{%A}}.[[id]] = {{%B}}.[[rif_a_entity]]')
->where(['=','{{%A}}.[[field]]',1])
->andWhere(['=','{{%B}}.[[field]]',1])
->createCommand()->rawSql;
```

**EDIT**

As after the discussion you want to keep the queries separate and don't want to use the above-proposed solution I would suggest you use the `joinWith` rather than trying to merge/join the 2 `ActiveQuery` Objects in the way you are trying to do, it was somehow supported in the `Yii1` as `CDbCriteria::merge()` but in `Yii2` merging of object have been replaced with the [**`joinWithRelations`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#joining-with-relations), so as you want to re-use a where clause from one of the queries and want to join with that table too you can do something like following.

Let's say we have two models `Products` and `Category`. `Products` has the foreign_key `cat_id`.I would define a relation in the model `Category` as `hasMany()`.

```
public function getProducts(){
    return $this->hasMany(Products::className(),['cat_id'=>'id']);
}
```

Then let's say I have the same situation like you and I want to keep both these queries separate and at the same time, I want to join the `Category` with the `Products` and use the `where` condition of the existing `Products` model query.

```
$cat=app\models\Category:find()->where(['=','status',1]);
$prod=app\models\Products:find()->where(['=','status',1]);

//in the first line below products is the name of the relation 
//and the second line is  how you merge the where clause from the $prod query with $cat query
$cat->joinWith(['products'])
->andWhere($prod->where);
```

if you try to see what query is built so far add the `createCommand()->rawSql` to the above.

```
$cat->joinWith(['products'])
->andWhere($prod->where)
->createCommand()
->rawSql;
```

this will output the following query

```
SELECT `category`.* FROM 
`category` 
LEFT JOIN 
`products` ON `products`.`cat_id` = `category`.`id` 
WHERE (`category`.`status` = 1) AND (`products`.`status` = 1)
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't suite perfectly my case.Is there a method to concatenate them with mantain them as active query.?

Comment: and if you could provide a little detail for the scenario you are trying to use them, it would make it easier to propose the exact solution, just add the details inside your Post. @giovaZ

Comment: Question Edited with more details. I'm not trying to make an union query but a join query

Comment: Yhea it Totally Works. It's also a good idea, i didn't think to use where array directly with joinWith() command. Thank you Muhammad

Comment: @giovaZ i updated the answer there was an error in the code `$cat->joinWith(['products'])->andWhere($cat->where)` should be `$cat->joinWith(['products'])->andWhere($prod->where)` sorry for that typo I hope you would have caught that while using the code just wanted you to get notified about it